# Fixing containers on browser zoom and resize

Tags: html, css

I've created the following banner below, using a triangle and rectangle in order to create the banner required over the image. However if the user zooms in on the browser these two containers have a gap between them. Any ideas how I could fix the two containers together or is there a better approach to writing this banner in general using CSS? Thanks in advance! :)

**Code:**

```
<html>
<style>
 #triangle {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-bottom: 150px solid red;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    top: 8px;
    position: relative;
}

#square {
    background-color:red;
    height:150px;
    width:300px;
    z-index: 3;
    margin-left: 8px;
    top: 8px;
    position: relative;
    color: white;
}

.align div {
  display:inline-block;
  float: left;
}


</style>
<div class="img">
    <img src="IMAGE HERE" alt="test" width="800" height="150">
</div>
<div class="align">
  <div id="square"> 
    <h1>
    Headline
    </h1>
    <p>
    Some text here!
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="triangle"></div>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: where is your html ?

Comment: Sorry about that my mistake. HTML added :)

Comment: I do not see any gap when looking at your code with JSFiddle

Answer (score 1):

I did not see any white space between the rectangle and the triangle on my browser. However I cleaned your code so you can try this :

```css
#triangle {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-bottom: 150px solid red;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  top: 8px;
  position: relative;
}

#square {
    background-color:red;
    height:150px;
    width:300px;
    z-index: 3;
    margin-left: 8px;
    top: 8px;
    position: relative;
    color: white;
}

.align div{
  display:inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.align {
  min-width:450px;
}
```

```html
<div class="align">
  <div id="square"> 
    <h1>
      Title
    </h1>
    <p>
    Some text here.......
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="triangle"></div>
</div>
```

**EDIT :** Fixed the align at 400% zoom. Added `min-width` to `.align` .

Comment: I changed "absolute" to "relative" as per your code but I still have the same issue. If you run it in JSFiddle you won't see the issue as you need to zoom in at 200% or above. I have had the issue in both Firefox and Chrome. Any other potential fixes or could this be wrote in a different way perhaps?

Comment: i did not just change `absolute` to `relative`. Can you give us a link to somewhere we can try and see the problem ?

Comment: I've added your updated css to the body of the question and added html tags so you can run it locally. If you zoom in to 400% on chrome you'll see the triangle drops down to the line below. I need to find a way to have them treated almost like one container. Is it possible to create this with one container rather than two?

Comment: I want to make sure the website is accessible and I want to ensure the two containers are almost treated like one.

Comment: Edited my answer. I could see your issue at 500% zoom AND resizing my screen. It's a very particular case. Tell me if it works now :)

Answer (score 0):

This problem is browser dependent and not all browsers showing same problem. Chrome may show perfect but mozilla might show problem. Also, Use reset css to avoid any browser dependent css property.